# Best practice for testing for data-testid in a nested component with React Testing Library?

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test to check if my app is rendering correctly. On the initial page Ive added a data-testid of "start". So my top level test checks that the initial component has been rendered.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
import App from "../App";

test("App - Check the choose form is rendered", () => {
  const wrapper = render(<App />);
  const start = wrapper.getByTestId("start");
  // console.log(start)
  // start.debug();
});
```

If I `console.log(start)` the I can see all the properties of the node. However if I try and `debug()` then it errors saying it's not a function.

My test above does seem to work. If I change the getByTestId from `start` to anything else then it does error. But I'm not using the `expect` function so am I violating best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to this question -

> Why `console.log(start)` works and why not `start.debug()`?

`getByTestId` returns an HTMLElement. When you use `console.log(start)`, the HTMLElement details are logged. But an HTMLElement does not have `debug` function. Instead, react-testing-library provides you with a `debug` function when you use `render` to render a component. So instead of using `start.debug()`, you should use `wrapper.debug()`.

> Because you don't have an `expect` function, is it a good practice to write such tests ?

I am not sure about what could be a great answer to this, but I will tell the way I use it. There are two variants for getting an element using data-testid - `getByTestId` and `queryByTestId`. The difference is that `getByTestId` throws error if an element with the test id is not found whereas `queryByTestId` returns null in such case. This means that `getByTestId` in itself is an assertion for presence of element. So having another expect which checks if the element was found or not will be redundant in case you are using `getByTestId`. I would rather use `queryByTestId` if I am to assert the presence/absence of an element. Example below -

```
test("App - Check the "Submit" button is rendered", () => {
 const { queryByTestId } = render(<App />)
 expect(queryByTestId('submit')).toBeTruthy()
});
```

I would use `getByTestId` in such tests where I know that the element is present and we have expects for the element's properties (not on the element's presence/absence). Example below -

```
test("App - Check the "Submit" button is disabled by default", () => {
 const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)
 expect(getByTestId('submit')).toHaveClass('disabled')
});
```

In the above test, if `getByTestId` is not able to find the submit button, it fails by throwing an error, and does not execute the `toHaveClass`. Here we don't need to test for presence/absence of the element, as this test is concerned only with the "disabled" state of the button.